# Insert default values from parent Model in HasMany relationship definition laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **Lesson** Model like this :

```
class Lesson extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;

        public    $primaryKey = 'lesson_id';
        .
        .
        .

         public function contents ()
         {
              return $this->hasMany('App\Content', 'lesson_id', 'lesson_id');
         }

     }
```

And in other hand **Content** Model is like :

```
class Content extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'content_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function lesson ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Lesson', 'lesson_id', 'lesson_id');
    }

}
```

As you see is a **hasMany** relationship between two model.

Content Model has this attributes :

```
content_id
lesson_id
contentable_id
contentable_type
order
```

and Lesson Model has these :

```
lesson_id
title
content
```

Now I want when saving contents of a specific lesson ,some Content Attributes automatically be filled based on Lesson Model attributes.

```
$lesson = Lesson::findOrFail($lessonID);
$lesson->contents()->create(
        [
            'contentable_id'   => $newUnit['unit_id'],
        ]
);
```

for example `lesson_id` of selected lesson be saved as `lesson_id` of Content Model and `App\Lesson` string as `contentable_type`.

How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do the changes below

**Lesson model**

```
class Lesson extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;

        public    $primaryKey = 'lesson_id';
        .
        .
        .

         public function contents ()
         {
              return $this->hasMany('App\Content', 'content');
         }

     }
```

**Content model**

```
class Content extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'content_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function lesson ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Lesson', 'content');
    }

}
```

**Then try it**

```
$lesson = Lesson::findOrFail($lessonID);
$content = new Content();
$content->contentable_id = '1111';
$lesson->contents()->save(content);
```

Comment: `content` fields of Lesson Model is a simple TEXT field and is not foreign key for Content Model in Lesson Model

Comment: You added `content` field to `$this->hasMany('App\Content', 'content');` and `$this->belongsTo('App\Lesson', 'content');` as foreign key  that is not correct. and I want `contentable_id` automatically filled by `lesson_id` of selected `Lesson` Model. you initialize it manualy.